# Slanted Box not Working in Safari/iOS Browsers

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make a slanted box (basically comprised of a center block element, and ::before & ::after slanted box elements). The issue is that my slanted boxes look fine in Chrome/Firefox, but the right (::after) slanted div doesn't seem to work correctly in Safari. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.slanted-box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.slanted-box p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: auto;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 4em;
}

.slanted-box-white {
    background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
}

.slanted-box-white p {
    color: black;
}

.slanted-box::before {
    content: '';
    height: 75px;
    width: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    transform: skewX(-10deg);
    transform-origin: top;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 0 0;
}
.slanted-box-white::before {
    background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
}
.slanted-box-white::after {
    background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
}
.slanted-box::after {
    content: '';
    height: 75px;
    width: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    transform: skewX(-10deg);
    transform-origin: bottom;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slanted-box slanted-box-white">
    <p>
    CAN A <span style="color:#A602B9"><span id="ticker" style="display: inline;">TACTIC</span></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

> JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hybridx24/8j101ux9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 0 0;` to `-webkit-transform-origin: top;` for `.slanted-box::before` css.

Change `-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 0 0;` to `-webkit-transform-origin: bottom;` for `.slanted-box::after` css.

Check it out. i have not tested on safari but it should work.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! Any reason you can explain what was wrong though?

Comment: Transformation changes X and Y axis of element. `-webkit-transform-origin: ` tells where to place an element along x and y axis in 2D transform and even z axis in 3D. Use of origin varies with transform used. Default values are `50% 50%` for origin which is center of element. You may want to read more on it.